# No implementation found for method write on channel plugins.it_nomads.com/flutter_secure_storage

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication

I was trying to store the login credentials of a user upon login, but I'm getting this error again and again. Things I've tried:

1. Restarting app
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling app
3. updating the flutter_secure_storage to the latest version

Here's the flutter doctor summary

````
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /home/piyush/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (12 days ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/piyush/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/piyush/Downloads/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /home/piyush/Downloads/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • RMX1851 • 580c132b • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)```
````

Comment: Did you give a full  restart after adding the package, I got the same error and when I gave a full restart it works properly. I used `flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1`

Answer (score 1):

"MissingPluginException" or "Implementation not found" errors thrown by plugins usually occurs when the plugin wasn't properly "installed" in the Flutter project.

These solutions may not be able to inject plugin dependencies into the platform-specific parts of the app. What you can do here is run flutter clean and flutter pub gets to rebuild the dependencies used in the project.

Also check that if that package supports your platform or not.if platform is not supported than find another package with your platform support.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new plugin, you need to re-build the application, the hot re-start doesn't build the application and your newly added is not included in your project unless built again. for that you should run

> flutter clean

> flutter pub get

> flutter run

if still not solved add read [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912)

Answer (score 0):

Generally this problem occurs when 2 or more plugins are incompatible with each other or with the current sdk version
To fix this change you kt code to this

package com.pharmdel_business

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
}

******but if any of you other plugin that only support FlutterActivity will stop working
If you face that issue then go to that plugin file and replace FlutterActivity with FlutterFragmentActivity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQf92.png)